# I can't get python to communicate with a Arduinio

Tags: python, arduino

**I can't get python to talk to my Arduino**, every time I try to initialize the connection it send me this error message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 322, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM0'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    ser1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 325, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 16] could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyACM0'
```

From this line:

> ser1 = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0, 9600)

The message suggests that the error is occurring in the actual function. I'm not sure what could be causing this so I'll show my code:

Python:

```
import serial
import time

s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
s.close()
s.open()
time.sleep(5)

s.write("test")
try:
    while True:
        response = s.readline()
        print (response)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
```

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("running");
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available()){
    byte recieved = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("recieved:");
    Serial.println(recieved, DEC);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything else open that might be talking to the board - the Arduino serial monitor, perhaps?

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, in the Arduino code I'm attempting to print what it receives. Every example I found did this so I didn't think it was a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the raspberry pi I'm working with opens a port to the arduino whenever you run:

> s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

Thus if you don't close the port before you kill the program the raspberry pi will classify the port as opened and not let you interact with it until its closed, and since the function the is required to use the s.close() function opens the port and returns the error, you can only fix the issue by rebooting your pi.

TLDR:
use s.close() before killing you program or you will have to restart your system